# Get userProfile mail by SP.FieldUserValue

Tags: 2013, user-profile, client-object-model

### **What I want**

Simply - the user's profile information to obtain the mail adress.

### **What I have**

A [`SP.FieldUserValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/jj246963(v=office.15).aspx) object filled with the user which mail I want to obtain. 
[image]

### **Approach**

```
MailContact: function () {
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens userspecific mailservice with a predefined mail and target
    /// </summary>
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        // Make sure PeopleManager is available 
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', function () {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);

            var PageUserProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(INSERTIDENTIFIERHERE);
            context.load(PageUserProperties);

            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    PageUserProperties;
                    debugger;
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    //todo errorhandling
                    console.log('Error while receiving the properties from the UserProfile');
                    console.log(args);
                }
            );
        });
    });        
}
```

### **Problem**

The information delivered by the `SP.FieldUserValue` is missing the domain/username data and it seems like `.getPropertiesFor()` function needs this information.

Isn't there a way to obtain a userprofile by a users id (the id is contained in the SP.FieldUserValue object)?

[Here is a wrapper used that accesses a SOAP service in 2007 and returns a user by ID. Do I really have to use this?](http://spjsblog.com/2011/09/18/accessing-user-profile-information-in-sharepoint-with-javascript-updated-version/)

### **Solution**

[Here's the answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/122571/10271)

```
MailContact: function () {
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens userspecific mailservice with a predefined mail and target
    /// </summary>
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var user = context.get_web().getUserById(this.Variables.Contact.get_lookupId());

    context.load(user);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            console.log(user.get_email());
            debugger;
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            //todo errorhandling
            console.log('Error while receiving the properties from the UserProfile');
            console.log(args);
        }
    );      
}
```

Comment: Since its 2013 why can't you use REST API?

Comment: The REST api would be another possible solution. It's just sad, that the SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager cannot deliver a userprofile by id..

Comment: The user id is specific to a site collection. User (login) name is unique. As the User Profile Service is an application service for a whole farm (with several web applications, each potentially with a lot of site collections), or even for other farms (in case it is shared across farms), it would be only possible to provide a method to lookup user profiles by id, if it would have a parameter of type site id, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first "convert" the `SP.FieldUserValue` (let's call it `fuv` in code) to an `SP.User` object, then have you already the login name you need:

```
var userId = fuv.get_lookupId();
var user = context.get_web().getUserById(userId);

context.Load(user);
context.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);

function onRequestSuccess() 
{       
  var loginName = user.get_loginName();    }

function onRequestFail(sender, args) 
{
  alert("error msg");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could retrieve the user's email address using [SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties.email property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679810(v=office.15).aspx):

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);

var properties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(accountName);
context.load(properties);

context.executeQueryAsync(
  function () {
     console.log(properties.get_email());
  },
  function (sender, args) {
     //Error handling goes here...
  }
);
```

Comment: accessing the properties is not the problem. getting the userprofile via a SP.FieldUserValue is because it only contains the display name and the id and not a domain/username information.